# Convolution algebra associated to a finite dimensional algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, frobenius-algebras

Given a finite dimensional $k$-algebra $A$ (we can assume it is given by a connected quiver with relations). One can form its trivial extension $T(A)$ (see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229412/trivial-extension-of-an-algebra ), which is a Frobenius algebra and thus it has a coalgebra structure, see for example the book by Kock on Frobenius algebras and 2D topological quantum field theories.

Now given any $k$-coalgebra $C$ and $k$-algebra $A$, we can form the convolution algebra $W_{C,A}={\rm Hom}_k(C,A)$.
This gives rise to (at least) two new algebras from a given algebra $A$, namely $W_{T(A),A}$ and $W_{T(A),T(A)}$ using that $T(A)$ has a coalgebra structure as a Frobenius algebra. I have no real experience with this topic, so sorry in case my questions are stupid.

> Question 1: Have either of the algebras $W_{T(A),A}$ or $W_{T(A),T(A)}$ been considered/described before? Are they quiver algebras and if so, can their quivers be described?
>
> Question 2: What do those two algebras look like in the concrete example where $A=kQ$ is a path algebra (maybe of Dynkin type)?
>
> Question 3: In case those questions are non-trivial, can those algebras be calculated by a computer algebra system like GAP/QPA?

Comment: For the benefit of anyone reading who, like me, did not know the terminology/definition of $T(A)$: it is what a Banach algebraist might write as $A\ltimes A^*$ where $A^*={\rm Hom}_k(A,k)$, and the crossed-product notation indicates that we think of $A^*$ as equipped with trivial multiplication with $A$ acting on $A^*$ from left and right in the canonical way. Alternatively, elements of $T(A)$ can be viewed as "matrices" of the form $\begin{pmatrix} a & b^* \\ 0 & a \end{pmatrix}$ with $a\in A$ and $b^*\in A^*$; the multiplication on $T(A)$ is then given by "matrix multiplication"

Comment: Just so I understand the concept of convolution algebra correctly: The convolution algebra is what we get when we use $Hom_k(C,A)\otimes Hom(C,A) = (C^\ast\otimes A) \otimes (C^\ast\otimes A) = (C\otimes C)^\ast\otimes (A\otimes A)$ and then apply multiplication and the dual of the comultiplication. Am getting this right? If so, I think $W_{C,A}$ is isomorphic to $W_{C,k} \otimes A$, correct?

Comment: @JohannesHahn I would think there is only one canonical way to get an algebra structure on this and it should be what you said. It looks like you are correct and so the convolution algebra might be rather boring, at least as a quiver algebra.

Comment: Indeed. If $C$ is a Frobenius algebra, then the convolution algebra $W_{C,k}$ is just $C$ itself via the isomorphismus $C\cong C^\ast$ that comes from the Frobenius structure.

Comment: well, I made a small mistake. I think, $C^{op} \cong W_{C,k}$ is the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

Question 3: The algebra constructions $W_{C,A}$ or even $W_{T(A),A}$ are not available in QPA.  There are no structures made for co-algebras in QPA.